# How to convert a mysql datetime column to just date?

Tags: mysql

Here is an explanation of how my table is set up (in sqlfiddle)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a54d/2

Basically, I have two columns. One is a varchar and contains a name. The other is a datetime and contains a certain date with a time.

I want to select rows where the date in the datetime matches today's date. I have tried things like...

```
select * from alerts_to_send where date_to_send = now()
select * from alerts_to_send where date_to_send = curdate()
```

I'm not exactly where to go from here... Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Just to re-clarify, I want to select the rows where today's date matches the date part of my datetime type column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  select * from alerts_to_send 
  where  DATE_FORMAT(date_to_send,'%m-%d-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a54d/7)

Comment: By that I mean that it worked perfectly btw... I will mark as answer when minimum time limit is met!

Comment: If your tables are very large, beware.  This will force a full table scan, even if the `date_to_send` column is indexed...

Comment: @Curt do you have any other suggestions then? This table will eventually become fairly large

Comment: @baba You might want to keep an indexed "date-date" (as opposed to DateTime) column, with the value cast from the date_to_send value.  This would have to maintained by a trigger (or change the routines that push data into the table to include the new column) but then you could query against that directly, and the database would not have to do conversions, obviating the need for table scans.    If you have no need for the time portion of date_to_send, it would be easiest yet to change the datatype of that column from DateTime to Date.

Comment: To elaborate (I was running out of space), if you did what I recommend above, you could write that query as `SELECT * FROM Alerts_to_Send WHERE actual_date = CurDate()`.  Any defined index on the `actual_date` field could be used, and the query would run *fast*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date_format` function for mysql

```
select * from alerts_to_send where date_format(date_to_send, "%m/%d/%Y") = date_format(now(), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Here is reference to date_format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to date_format function you can convert the datetime to date:

```
select * from alerts_to_send where cast(date_to_send as date) = curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be even shorter:

`select * from alerts_to_send where date(date_to_send) = date(now())`

But you will have problem with using index on it so better will be:

`select * from alerts_to_send where date_to_send >= date(now()) and date_to_send < date(now()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`